# Google OneTap with Codetrix Capacitor failed, resulting in 'popup_closed_by_user' error

Tags: angular, capacitor, google-one-tap

(English is not my native language, please understand.)

As mentioned, the project requirement is to use the Codetrix Capacitor Google Auth package
in an Angular + Capacitor framework environment:
https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

The program content is as follows:
app\pages\login\login\login.component.ts:

```
import { GoogleAuth } from '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';
...
  constructor() {
    const firebaseConfig = {...};
    GoogleAuth.initialize();
    this.firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }

  async clickSignIn() {
    try {
      const user = await GoogleAuth.signIn(); //here error
      console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {  console.log(error);  }
  }
```

Subsequently, the 'popup_closed_by_user' error occurs
The current project experiencing login failure:
https://gitlab.com/aloo31124/space-in-ng

Successful reference example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzQtA-VXoP4&t=12s
https://github.com/narottamgoyal/MyFirstIonicApp

I hope to receive some guidance on this matter. thanks.